is there a way for a PHPUnit extension to get information from within the test?
I'm trying to implement a PHPUnit extension and I need data that the test's setUp() put in a static property on a class. (Specifically, Drupal's Database::getAllConnectionInfo().)
It's not there when the extension gets the PHPUnit\Event\TestRunner\Finished event. I assume that's because the extension runs in the test runner process, not the test process.
Is there any way for a PHPUnit extension to get data from the test process?
